# Is there a web host that will allow me to run nodejs?

Tags: node.js, web-hosting

Are there any web hosts out there offering node js support?

Comment: Basically any VPS or dedicated server.

Comment: FWIW: if anyone is curious why it got closed as "too localized", for my vote, it's because hosts come and go, and what services they provide are fluid. This will only be valid for so long a period of time.

Comment: Also found that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648993/where-can-i-host-a-node-js-app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are plenty.

- [no.de](https://no.de/) are the webservers that joyent run themself.
- [nodejitsu](http://www.nodejitsu.com/) also offers hosting
- [nodester](http://nodester.com/)

> https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/hosting

is a list of hosts managed on the joyent wiki on github. A wiki. So if you can't use one, update it. If you find one not listed, update it.

Comment: awesome, thanks! Somehow Google failed me miserably...